# How to target specific vue table element?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm setting up a list that fetches from a database and displays a list of orders. `onclick` of the button, I would like to show the stars-rating div only in the row it was clicked on. How do I make a vue button trigger the appearance of a div only in the row that it is in.

I've tried using `v-on:click=` function to call another function in js but didn't seem to work. Here both templates are contained in

```
    <div id="wrapper">
         <v-toolbar flat color="white">
              <v-toolbar-title style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;">Order 
               History</v-toolbar-title>
               <v-spacer></v-spacer>
               <d style="margin-right:20px;color:#a7a7a7;font-family: 'Raleway', 
               sans-serif;">click on an order for more information</d>
                         </v-toolbar>
                         <v-data-table
                            :headers="headers"
                            :items="orders"
                            :expand="expand"
                            item-key="number"
                            >
                            <template v-slot:items="props">
                               <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
<!--trigger using this button-->   <td class="text-xs-left" style='font- 
                                    weight:400;'><v-btn v-on:click="greet" 
                                   class="dark">{{ props.item.review }}</v-btn> 
                                   </td>
                               </tr>
                            </template>
                            <template v-slot:expand="props" style="font- 
                               weight:500">
                               <v-data-table
                                  :items="[props.item]"
                                  :expand="expand"
                                  item-key="name"
                                  hide-actions
                                  >
                                  <template v-slot:headers="props">
                                  </template>
                                  <template v-slot:items="props">
                                     <td width="15%" class="text-xs-left" 
                                      style='font-weight:300;'>
<!--trigger this div  -->                    <div class="star-rating"></div>
                                     </td>
                                  </template>
                               </v-data-table>
                            </template>
                         </v-data-table>
                      </div>
```

//JS

```
var v = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
     methods: {
         greet: function () {
               $(".stars-rating").hide();
          }
      },
  data() {
    return {
      expand: true,
      headers: [
      {
        text: 'Order Number',
        align: 'left',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'number',
        width: '10%' },

      { text: 'Name/Message', value: 'name',
        align: 'left',
        width: '15%' },
      { text: 'Date/Start', value: 'date',
        align: 'left',
        width: '10%' },
      { text: 'Time/End', value: 'time',
        align: 'left',
        width: '10%' },
      { text: 'Provider/Receipts', value: 'provider',
        align: 'left',
        width: '10%' },
      { text: 'Amount/Labor', value: 'amount',
        align: 'left',
        width: '15%' },
      { text: 'Status/Tracking', value: 'status',
        align: 'left',
        width: '15%' },
      { text: 'Confirmation/Review', value: 'review',
        align: 'left',
        width: '15%' }],

      orders: [],

    };
  } });
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with

```
<div class="star-rating" v-if="props.expanded"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove the `@click` from your `<tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">` element.

In your `greet` function, you have to change the `expand` flag, something like:

```js
greet: function () {
 this.expand = false
}
```

As you are already biding the `expand` state with the `v-data-table` `expand` prop, it should work

```js
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="orders"
    :expand="expand"
    item-key="number"
>
```

Comment: The rows are already expand when clicked on to display further information. The issue is with getting the stars to show only after the button in the row is clicked, not after the row itself is is clicked as it is now.

Comment: If you create a reproduction of the problem in a codepen or fiddle I will be able to help, based just on in your code is difficult

Comment: I'm trying to just have the review stars show when the "Mark Completed" button is pressed for a completed order. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m85te3wj/#&togetherjs=yy81lN03IP)